# "Ломается" клавиатура в Delphi после применения keybd_event()

Tags: delphi, winapi, клавиатура

Передо мной стала довольно простая задача: симитировать нажатие комбинации клавиш
(CTRL+C; CTRL+V; CTRL+X) я решил применить для этого API функцию `KeyBD_Event()` :

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,0,0);
keybd_event(ord('C'),0,0,0);
```

Но после этих действий происходит нечто необъяснимое. У меня ПОЛНОСТЬЮ МЕНЯЕТСЯ ПОРЯДОК виртуальных клавиш. Например, нажимаю на "А" - открывается почтовый клиент, жму на ALT - открывается хелп(который обычно вызывается на F1).

Что вы мне можете посоветовать в этом случае?

Comment: Не забывайте отпускать клавишу после нажатия, вызывая метод с флагом KEYEVENTF_KEYUP в качестве третьего аргумента.

Comment: Спасибо. Это единственная проблема?

Comment: Не ясно, почему в вызове scan code клавиши задан как `0`; его следует передавать в качестве второго аргумента. Получить код можно используя [`MapVirtualKey`][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хех) все получилось, но как-то непонятно. Зачем нажимать на каждую клавишу дважды(?):

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), 0, 0); //1
keybd_event(Ord('X'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('X'), 0), 0, 0); //2
keybd_event(Ord('X'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('X'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //2
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //1
```

Comment: Именно так. Тут не двойное нажатие, а нажатие и отпускание клавиши (флаг `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`).